# how to convert from Text to String, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have in my application several select, like this:

```
<select class="select" id="t_0" name="t[0]">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
  <option value="4">d</option>
</select>

<select class="select" id="t_1" name="t[1]">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
  <option value="4">d</option>
</select>
```

I need in my Javascript / coffeescript to make a method that returns true if all the selected values have text: "b".

```
  _tAreB: -> 
    selecteds = $('select[id^=t_] option:selected').contents()
    for t in selecteds 
      return false unless t == "b"
    return true
```

The `==` fails, because `t` is a `Text`, and can't compare to a `String`, How can I convert t to a String as well?

UPDATE: 
If on the console I do:

```
>a = $('select[id^=t_] option:selected').contents()
>a
<- ["b","b","a"]
>a.constructor.prototype
<- []
>a[0].constructor.prototype
<- Text {splitText: function, replaceWholeText: function, getDestinationInsertionPoints: function, substringData: function, appendData: function…}
```

Comment: Use as `selecteds = $('select[id^=t_] option:selected').text()`

Comment: `text()` returns a string like "bbbbb", and it's not good for me.

Comment: @Juhana, I've updated the question, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the class of the object is "Text" imho

Comment: do you have an online example of this code?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not available online, 

but the solution from Jack Pattishall worked nicely, thanks to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you're dealing with a comparison between `text` and `string`. There's actually an easy way to address this: reference the `textContent` of `text`.

(Unfortunately, I don't do coffeescript, but here's the compiled coffeescript in JS with changes)

```
({
  _tAreB: function() {
    var selecteds, t, _i, _len;
    selecteds = $('select[id^=t_] option:selected').contents();
    for (_i = 0, _len = selecteds.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      t = selecteds[_i];
      if (t.textContent !== "b") {
          return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating:

http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/8qmrogL7/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a similar coffeescript to:

```
(($) ->
    checkForMatches = ->
        searchBucket = []

        # in this example, the select elements have a class '.select'
        selectedOptions = $ '.select option:selected'
        selectedCount = selectedOptions.length
        searchBucket.push option for option in selectedOptions when option.text is 'b'

        allMatch = searchBucket.length is selectedCount
        console.log allMatch
        return allMatch

    # try to test with a selected option set to 'bb'
    # note: currently this will print true since selected options match on document load
    $(checkForMatches)
)(jQuery)
```

Full example in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4IUBrz?p=preview)